# What does ああまでされて mean in this sentence?

Tags: slang, idioms

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm reading a manga (full of slang, which makes it so hard!) and I ran across this sentence:

(panel 1)

- 俺だったら素直に喜べたか！？
- ああまでされて

(panel 2)
追い詰められて！？

To get you the context of the whole sentence, this occurs in the middle of two people's conversation about a third person, who's working hard because the third individual knows everyone will stand for him. The character who thinks this line had never realized the third guy felt pressed by their support, and in fact was feeling envious that the other guy was doing better than him despite being a novice.

My best guess is that the exchange goes something like this: 
"Had it been me, would I be pleased with it? / Had I been put under such pressure?" I have absolutely no clue of what ああまでされて means here. Is it あんなにまで or even あそこまで?

Thanks again for any insight!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ああまで is interchangeable with あんなにまで, あそこまで or あんなことまで in this case. ああ here refers to something cruel which was done to them in the story.

ああまでされて literally means "even things like that is done, (and/but/so ...)". You can perhaps translate this as "Even after (someone) did such a thing to you/me/us..."